# React Native Mapview component into Expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-component

I wish to add the [React Native MapView Component](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) to the new project I have created using expo. The instructions explain that I need to modify files in the iOS and Android folders, but expo doesn't generate iOS and Android folders, right?

Can I use this component in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's included as per https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/

"No setup required for use within the Expo app, or within a standalone app for iOS."

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView style={{flex: 1}} />
    );
  }
}
```